# GstCaps filter issue

Tags: c++, audio, gstreamer

trying to create filter using caps:

```
GMainLoop *loop; 
            GstElement *pipeline, *source, *demuxer, *decoder,  *typefind, *conv, *sink;; 
            GstBus *bus; 
            guint bus_watch_id; 


            loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE); 

            pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("audio-player"); 
            source   = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc",       "file-source"); 
            typefind = gst_element_factory_make ("typefind", "typefinder"); 
            demuxer  = gst_element_factory_make ("oggdemux",      "ogg-demuxer"); 
            decoder  = gst_element_factory_make ("vorbisdec",     "vorbis-decoder"); 
            conv     = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert",  "converter"); 
            sink     = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audio-output"); 

            if (!pipeline || !source || !demuxer || !decoder || !conv || !sink) { 
                    return -1; 
            } 
            g_signal_connect (typefind, "have-type", G_CALLBACK (cb_typefound), loop); 
            g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "location", name_of_file, NULL); 

            bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(pipeline)); 
            bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch(bus, bus_call, loop); 
            gst_object_unref(bus); 

            gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, typefind, demuxer, decoder, conv, sink, NULL); 

            GstCaps *my_caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("audio/x-raw","rate", G_TYPE_INT, 384,NULL); 


            gboolean test=false; 
            test = gst_element_link_filtered(source,typefind, my_caps); 
            test = gst_element_link(typefind, demuxer); 
            test = gst_element_link_many(decoder, conv,sink, NULL); 


            g_signal_connect(demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_pad_added), decoder); 
......
```

**Debug: gsttypefindelement.c(1169): gst_type_find_element_loop (): /GstPipeline:a 
udio-player/GstTypeFindElement:typefinder: 
stream stopped, reason not-linked**

> Var test == 1 after gst_element_link_filtered(source,typefind,
>   my_caps);
>
> test == 0 after gst_element_link(typefind, demuxer);
>
> test == 1 after gst_element_link_many(decoder, conv,sink, NULL);

If I just change gst_element_link_filtered on gst_element_link all going ok and file plays. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to also have posted this to the gst-devel mailing list and you have a reply there:

http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/GstCaps-filter-issue-td4672796.html

Setting a filter caps of raw audio between the filesrc and the demuxer while you seem to want to play an OGG file is wrong. You should explain better what you want to do in order for us to provide some more refined guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I also posted this: "Thanks for the response!  Yes, oggdemux really need audio/ogg on sink pad. Now I trying to link audioconvert to autoaudiosink with the same caps and with caps with "audio/ogg" type but still have same error.  I think I don't quite understand something, can you explain?  I trying to change rate of my audio."